# How to make a PUT API HTTPS request [reactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

currently working on an admin control panel for a list display of cards. The cards are either a video based one, or text-based one depending on the URL sent to it. The API is locally hosted and passes information such as id,Title,URL,ThumbnailURL. I have created a successful delete method that removes a card from an API. I have two modules, HelpCard.tsx and HelpList.tsx.

The code that has the deleteProduct and EditProduct functions is on HelpList.tsx and is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HelpCard from "./HelpCard";
import "../help/HelpCard.css";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";
import { Button } from "components/ui";

interface State {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard[];
  error: null;
  response: {};
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface SingleAdminHelpCard {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface Props {}

export default class HelpList extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    title: "",
    thumbnail: "",
    id: "",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/videos/",
    adminhelpcard: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 1,
    activePage: 1,
    error: null,
    response: {}
  };

  loadAdminHelpCard = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const adminhelpcard = prevState.adminhelpcard;
          return {
            adminhelpcard: [...prevState.adminhelpcard, ...res.data],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  static props: any;

  async componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ adminhelpcard: res.data });
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            adminhelpcard: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  deleteProduct(id: any) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;

    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "DELETE"
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );

    console.log(this.state.id);
  }

  editProduct(id: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;

    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "PUT"
    };
    formData.append("textCardTitle", this.state.title);
    formData.append("textCardURL", this.state.url);
    formData.append("textCardThumbnail", this.state.thumbnail);

    return fetch("http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    }).then((response) => response.json());
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.adminhelpcard);
    return (
      <div>
        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.adminhelpcard ? (
            <div className="row">
              <InfiniteScroll
                pageStart={1}
                loadMore={this.loadAdminHelpCard}
                hasMore={this.state.url ? true : false}
                threshold={0}
                loader={
                  <div className="loader" key={0}>
                    Loading ...
                  </div>
                }>
                {this.state.adminhelpcard.map((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard, i) => (
                  <HelpCard
                    id={adminhelpcard.id}
                    key={adminhelpcard.id + i}
                    title={adminhelpcard.title}
                    url={adminhelpcard.url}
                    thumbnail={adminhelpcard.thumbnail}
                    deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct.bind(this)}
                    editProduct={this.editProduct.bind(this)}
                  />
                ))}
              </InfiniteScroll>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <h1>Loading Cards</h1>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The code that submits the requests are on HelpCard.tsx . I have set an OnClick within the edit / delete buttons of the cards that are called from HelpList.tsx . Even though the Delete button works, the edit one can't seem to work too well and I'm unsure why. Clicking the submit edit button just seems to refresh the page. The code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../help/HelpCard.css";
import "../help/HelpList";
import Dialog from "../help/Dialog";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

interface Props {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  deleteProduct: (id: any) => void;
  editProduct: (id: any) => void;
}
/**/

interface State {
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  id: string;
  url: string;
  imageLoading?: boolean;
  tooManyRequests?: boolean;
  _input?: HTMLInputElement;
}

export default class HelpCard extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    url: "",
    id: "",
    title: "",
    imageLoading: true,
    tooManyRequests: false,
    thumbnail: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { url, title, thumbnail } = this.props;
    const id = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length - 2];

    this.setState({
      url,
      id,
      title,
      thumbnail,
      imageLoading: true,
      tooManyRequests: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const isThumbnail = this.state.thumbnail;
    const adminhelpcard = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          {isThumbnail ? (
            <div className="horizontalCard">
              <div className="innerCard">
                <div className="leftImage">
                  <img
                    className="Sprite"
                    onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
                    onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
                    src={this.state.thumbnail}
                    style={
                      this.state.tooManyRequests
                        ? { display: "none" }
                        : this.state.imageLoading
                        ? { display: "null" }
                        : { display: "null" }
                    }
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="rightText">
                  <div className="card-body">
                    {this.state.title}
                    <div className="cardButtons">
                      <Popup trigger={<button className="btn"> Edit</button>} position="right center">
                        <form id="videoCardEdit" style={{ width: "auto", height: "auto" }}>
                          <div>
                            <div>
                              <label>Title:</label>
                              <input id="videoCardTitle" defaultValue={this.state.title}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label>URL:</label>
                              <input id="videoCardURL" defaultValue={this.state.url}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                              <input id="videoCardThumbnail" defaultValue={this.state.thumbnail}></input>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <button onClick={() => this.props.editProduct(this.props.id)} id="confirmModalBtn">
                            confirm
                          </button>
                          <button id="cancelModalBtn">cancel</button>
                        </form>
                      </Popup>
                      <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(this.props.id)} className="btn">
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="styledLink" to={`adminhelpcard/${this.state.id}`}>
              <div className="card">
                <div>
                  {this.state.tooManyRequests ? (
                    <h6 className="mx-auto">
                      <span className="badge badge-danger mt-2"></span>
                    </h6>
                  ) : null}
                  <div className="card-body mx-auto">
                    <div className="card-title">
                      {this.state.title
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .split(" ")
                        .map((letter) => letter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + letter.substring(1))
                        .join(" ")}
                      <div className="cardButtons">
                        <Popup trigger={<button className="btn"> Edit</button>} position="right center">
                          <form id="textCardEdit" style={{ width: "auto", height: "auto" }}>
                            <div>
                              <div>
                                <label>Title:</label>
                                <input id="textCardTitle" defaultValue={this.state.title}></input>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <label>URL:</label>
                                <input id="textCardURL" defaultValue={this.state.url}></input>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                                <input id="textCardThumbnail" defaultValue={this.state.thumbnail}></input>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <button id="confirmModalBtn">confirm</button>
                            <button id="cancelModalBtn">cancel</button>
                          </form>
                        </Popup>
                        <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(this.props.id)} className="btn ">
                          Delete
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Clicking on the edit button opens a modal dialog that has the current cards URL,Title and Thumbnail's loaded into the input. I was trying to make it so that if any changes are made to the inputs, the admin can click submit and it will change the url / title / thumbnail on the API.

Is there something missing on my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `form` tag will redirect the page on submit to the target specified.

prevent the default action of the `form` tag on submit action.

`<form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()} id="textCardEdit" style={{ width: "auto", height: "auto" }}>`

You can learn more about `form` tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp).

Comment: When posting now it seems to return the console error :

POST http://localhost:3000/videos/$%7Bid%7D 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I think it's to do with the HelpList.tsx's editProduct function with hte URL

Comment: localhost:3000/videos/$%7Bid%7D, this URL contains '$' symbol. If it is a part of your card id, then use encodeURIComponent(url) to encode the special symbols that are components of URL to their respective code. $ -> %24

Comment: as you can see, It's set as "return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`," which has worked with the deleteProduct function. Can you give me more details about what you mean?

Comment: In your editProduct function, change the double quotes(") to backtick(\`) in `fetch("http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}", ...` OR use `apiUrl` variable in the fetch function.

Comment: I already have tried doing both of your suggestions, it seems to edit the products but it removes everything except for the Id so the data stored looks like as follows:

{
    "id": 1,
    "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e-.mp4",
    "title": "How to train your dragon video",
    "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/l3uyjXJl2Fw/hqdefault.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  },

Comment: id:2 used to previously look like 1, when I tried editing the title and hitting submit, it changes it to that.

Comment: That must have to do something with the REST API implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200232/discussion-between-salim-khan-and-zadders).

Comment: Available whenever you are :)